# ORA-06550   wrong number or types of arguments when calling Oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle, ora-06550

Have been fighting this for two days and am very frustrated but feel like I am making progress.  After reviewing Oracle's online docs I am here.  Receiving the following error upon code execution:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 15: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'P_SALTEDHASH' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Stored procedure looks like this:

```
PROCEDURE stored_procedure_name ( p_passwd            IN  VARCHAR2,
                          p_salt              IN  VARCHAR2,
                          p_saltedhash_passwd OUT VARCHAR2
                        )
```

My code:

```
        string stored_procedure_name = "stored_procedure_name";

        // create the command object
        OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = stored_procedure_name;
        cmd.BindByName = true;

        //Oracle Parameters necessary for the p_saltedhash function          
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_passwd", p_passwd);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_salt", p_salt);

        OracleParameter p_saltedhash_passwd = 
            new OracleParameter("p_saltedhash_passwd", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
        p_saltedhash_passwd.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_saltedhash_passwd);



        // execute the pl/sql block
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Response.Write("Pin hash is: " + p_saltedhash_passwd);`
```

Comment: It would seem a good idea to specify `OracleDbType.Varchar2` for the first 2 params as well. I doubt it is the default and wouldn't trust auto-conversion.

Comment: This code works, but how do I input the values for p_passwd and p_salt? Right now the output is literally "Salt licked hash: p_saltedhash_passwd"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
p_saltedhash_passwd.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

to

```
p_saltedhash_passwd.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Comment: Tried that but received ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at "SOME_FUNCTION_I_DON'T_RECOGNIZE", line 77 ORA-06512: at "SOME_FUNCTION_I_DON'T_RECOGNIZE", line 130 ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: @Geekender I don't know enough about the procedure/function you are using to help there... from what I see you are using the officially deprecated OracleClient from MS which you should think about changing.

Comment: I did change this line `OracleParameter p_saltedhash_passwd = 
                new OracleParameter("p_saltedhash_passwd", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2000);`  And it sort of works.  Now it is printing something just not the data.  I am using the Oracle.DataAccess.Client from Oracle.

Comment: @Geekender to print the output param `p_saltedhash_passwd` use `p_saltedhash_passwd.Value.ToString()` in the call to `Response.Write`